# Sqlite - Multiple INNER JOIN on same Table with Limit

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my Android application I have a Sqlite Database with a Question Table with 6 topic-IDs. Now I want to get a certain number of questions of every topic. That means: 15 questions with topic-ID 1, 5 with topic-ID 2, 7 with topic-ID 3 and 4 and 3 with topic-ID 5 and 6.

I think I need a multipe inner join and the limit function but I don't know much about building queries like this.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method is to use `union all` and `limit`:

```
(select q.* from questions q where q.topicid = 1 order by random() limit 15) union all
(select q.* from questions q where q.topicid = 2 order by random() limit 5) union all
(select q.* from questions q where q.topicid in (3, 4) order by random() limit 7) union all
(select q.* from questions q where q.topicid in (5, 6) order by random() limit 3) ;
```

I didn't realize that SQLite seems to have problems with subqueries and `union all`.  In any case, this version seems to [work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/45e7b8/6):

```
with q1 as
    (select q.* from questions q where q.topicid = 1 order by random() limit 15),
     q2 as
    (select q.* from questions q where q.topicid = 2 order by random() limit 5),
    q34 as 
    (select q.* from questions q where q.topicid in (3, 4) order by random() limit 7),
    q56 as
    (select q.* from questions q where q.topicid in (5, 6) order by random() limit 3)
select * from q1 union all
select * from q2 union all
select * from q34 union all
select * from q56;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting a SQL syntax error when I use your query.

Comment: Subqueries are allowed as-is only where a table name is allowed (in the FROM clause), or as a scalar subquery. UNION wants a 'real' query, so you have to wrap another query around it.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate rows from mutiple queries, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound).

LIMIT is not allowed on a query in a compound query, so it has to be moved into a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Questions
               WHERE TopicID = 1
               ORDER BY random() LIMIT 15)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Questions
               WHERE TopicID = 2
               ORDER BY random() LIMIT  5)
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: When I use your query I'm also getting a SQL syntax error.

Comment: The final ORDER BY does not work without a separate indirection, but you didn't ask for it ...

Answer (score 0):

try this example used to combine rows from two or more tables http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp